# Using .cache() with data preparation in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Can anyone explain  what is the purpose of `.cache()` in this line when using `tensorflow_datasets`

```
train_batches = train_examples.cache().shuffle(num_examples // 4).map(format_image).batch(32).prefetch(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, it caches the samples in memory (or on disk if a filename is provided). For example, if `train_examples` includes expensive preprocessing, the preprocessing does not need to be repeated for each epoch at the cost of increased memory consumption.

Note that due to the order, all methods called *after* `.cache()` are still performed each epoch. Depending on the situation, it might be beneficial, to call `.map()` before `.cache()`. However, shuffling and batching should usually be called last.

For details, please check the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache).

Comment: In that case, shuffle will be performed only once. One should be careful with the cache. Also, if no filename is given, for large datasets, computer can go out of ram pretty fast.

Comment: Could you explain more about the filename because i got one message that there is no enough ram?. how to avoid it

Comment: @MYASS This is well documented online, I added a link.